# JdbcTemplate.update doesn't update my database

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Within my .jsp file i'm calling an object that is suppose to update my database using JdbcTemplate.update.  I'm using Spring MVC framework, tomcat and mySql. Thank you for any help.

**Code from my .jsp file:**

```
 <% FileDataDAO fileDataDAO = new FileDataDAO();

          fileDataDAO.test();

 %>
```

**Code within my .java file:**

```
@Component("fileDataDao")
public class FileDataDAO {

private JdbcTemplate jdbc;
private DataSource dataSource;

public FileDataDAO() {}

@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {

    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

}
public void test(){

    String sql = "INSERT INTO myguests(id) VALUES(?)";
    jdbc.update(sql,5);
}
}
```

**daoContext.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">


   <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc.dao">
          <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" 
             expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
   </context:component-scan>

   <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jdbc/TestDB" id="dataSource"
          expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>


 </beans>
```

**Specific error:**

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/pages/home.jsp at line 54

    51: 
    52:           <% FileDataDAO fileDataDAO = new FileDataDAO();
    53: 
    54:     fileDataDAO.test();
    55: 
    56: %>
    57: 


    Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:172)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: Just for information, It's a bad practise to use scriptlet in the jsp. You use Spring MVC, so put your business logic in the controller directly.

Comment: Thank you.  I will most def change it.  I am just trying to learn at this point.  Once I have a better understanding on how Spring MVC works I'll most def fine tune it.

Answer (score 0):

You made a  **FileDataDAO fileDataDAO = new FileDataDAO()** but you use Autowired. You need to get your instance from the contexte (spring, CDI...)

Comment: I do have a daoContext.xml file and I did set up a file listener within my web.xml file telling it to load it.  Is the daoContext.xml file what you are referinng to or something different?  I did add my daoContext code up above.  I apologize I am new to spring MVC.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe this can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139121/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-autowire-spring-beans-in-a-jsp