# Set JSP list box contents from DB on every request

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a single JSP that serves multiple methods in a Controller -- it is the result of Add, Edit, Delete, etc. It may even serve multiple Controllers, so it's used in a lot of places.

This JSP always has a List Box displaying a set of records. So I need to re-fetch the list on every request every time this JSP is displayed.

- On the one hand, I can do `request.setAttribute("contents",
  service.getForms())` and then retrieve this Req. Attr., but this has
  to be done on **every method** that uses the JSP. There may be dozens,
  and it's redundant.
- Can't use a Session object, the list may change depending some
  Add/Delete operations, so it needs to be re-fetched.
- I was thinking of scriptlets: in this case, although generally
  ill-advised, there's a single JSP, so the List Box can be populated
  on the JSP level, without worrying about controllers. But
  unfortunately I can't do this:

  `<% service.getForms(); %>`

My service is auto-wired. According to this thread, I can't expose autowired objects to JSPs:
[What is the cleanest way to autowire Spring Beans in a JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139121/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-autowire-spring-beans-in-a-jsp)

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("Myervice")
private MyService service;
```

What's the best way to go about it?

Comment: What would be so wrong with creating a new method in the controller to fetch the data and when the page loads, use an ajax call to call the new method and retrieve the data and populate the box.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. There's an AJAX call now from the JSP in the onReady which doesn't depend on any request attributes and always has the list.